# How do I combine @font-face and @media declarations?

Tags: css, fonts, mobile

I'd like to build a common typography stylesheet with a very small number of selectors. As such, I'd far prefer to use `@media` sections for the various versions rather than create different files, each with only a few lines of content.

I'd also like to add some `@font-face` declarations, but I'd prefer not to force mobile users to download the fonts given their limited bandwidth.

Can I put the `@font-face` declaration within the `@media` block or do they have to both be top-level? If the latter, how can I tell the mobile browsers they don't need to bother downloading the font?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [CSS2 spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/media.html) suggests something like this.

1. Put your `@font-face` declarations in a separate CSS file, such as `fancyfonts.css`.
2. Load `fancyfonts.css` in your main CSS file, but with a media-target declaration:

   ```
   @import url("fancyfonts.css") screen;
   ```
3. Specify your fancy font in the `font-family` attribute.

   ```
   body {
     font-family: 'My Fancy Font', serif;
   }
   ```

Media which don't load the `fancyfonts.css` will fall back to the other fonts you specify -- in this example, `serif`.

Answer (score 1):

> Can I put the @font-face declaration within the @media block or do they have to both be top-level?

This seems unspecified by the current Working Draft of the [CSS3 Fonts](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-fonts/) module. However, the [CSS Validator](http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/) rejects font-face-inside-media, so it's probably best avoided.